# Wrap template code with shortcodes

Tags: shortcode

A client of mine wishes to use the plugin [Content Locker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-locker/). The template in question doesn't have a content area the client can use and hence I need to use the [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function.

I know how to implement but not close?

```
<?php do_shortcode('[signinlocker id="506"]'); ?>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="columns resource_downloads">
    <?php if ( have_rows('_downloads_group') ) : ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('_downloads_group') ) : the_row(); ?>
      <div class="column v-align-top">
        <figure class="download__img outer-1by1">
          <img class="inner-1by1" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_sub_field('_file_image'), 'download' )[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_field('_file_image_alt'); ?>" width="150" height="150">
        </figure>
        <div class="resource_downloads-info stack__sm">
          <h3><?php the_sub_field('_file_title'); ?></h3>
          <p><?php the_sub_field('_file_description'); ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-wrap">
         <a class="button primary" href="<?php the_sub_field('_file_download_button'); ?>" title="<?php the_sub_field('_file_download_button_title'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('_file_download_button_label'); ?></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php do_shortcode('[/signinlocker]'); ?> // This is not correct?
```

I have too much "content" to use the `echo do_shortcode( '[iscorrect]' . $text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode . '[/iscorrect]' );` example in the WordPress documentation.

How can I "wrap" the necessary code with `[signinlocker id="506"]` shortcode.

Comment: *I have too much "content"*, what do you mean by that? you need to loop that content and thats the problem?

Comment: There are multiple lines of looped php and html, hence I think too much for a variable. The content is slightly irrelevant. The issue is the shortcode needs to wrap around whatever it contains.

Comment: A variable is just a container, if the final content is 100% string, no object and arrays, there should be no problem doing that. If you have less then 2GB string you should not have problems

Answer (score 0):

Using output buffering seems like the way to go in this case, `ob_start()` to start buffering, then `ob_get_clean()` to get and clean the buffering.

```html
<?php ob_start(); ?>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="columns resource_downloads">
    <?php if ( have_rows('_downloads_group') ) : ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('_downloads_group') ) : the_row(); ?>
      <div class="column v-align-top">
        <figure class="download__img outer-1by1">
          <img class="inner-1by1" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_sub_field('_file_image'), 'download' )[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_field('_file_image_alt'); ?>" width="150" height="150">
        </figure>
        <div class="resource_downloads-info stack__sm">
          <h3><?php the_sub_field('_file_title'); ?></h3>
          <p><?php the_sub_field('_file_description'); ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-wrap">
         <a class="button primary" href="<?php the_sub_field('_file_download_button'); ?>" title="<?php the_sub_field('_file_download_button_title'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('_file_download_button_label'); ?></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
$output = ob_get_clean();
echo do_shortcode('[signinlocker id="506"]' . $output . '[/signinlocker]');
?>
```

Comment: This looks good, but it currently isn't working. I'm just having the client check their API and I'm double checking the settings. Thanks in advance